# simplexml_load_string error

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml

This is my System.log
what problem...how can i modification for this error ?
my homepage have many usage cpu. (sometimes cpu 100% and not opened homepage)
please help me !

```
2016-02-15T07:52:34+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T07:52:34+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T07:52:34+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T07:52:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T07:52:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T07:52:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T07:52:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T07:52:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T07:52:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T07:53:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T07:53:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T07:53:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T08:12:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T08:12:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T08:12:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T08:15:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T08:15:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-15T08:15:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
```

Comment: You asked the question before and got answers: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100281/system-log-error-simplexml-load-string-extra-content-at-the-end-of-the-document please comment on the answers or edit your original question if you need more information or want to give more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your layout XML files doesn't have closing tag. Looks like for this tag:

```
<reference name="left">
```

There no

```
</reference>
```

Anyway I'd recommend to search in layout folder for this text: `<reference name="left">` and in found files look for XML error.

Comment: i can't find broblem code..

Comment: 이시우 you need searh all layout  file where `<`  tag properly add or end

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that this problem refers to some of your layout xml files. And you just need to find which one. There is also another way. You have some theme **your_package/your_theme**. Find the page which cause new issues in log file. And try to hide files from layout folder one by one (you can do it via rename or move to some another folder which is non inside layout. Better out of magento dir) and refresh the page. Of course some of content can disappear after that, don't be afraid. Your general task is to find file which generate an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some info to @zhartaunik's answer.

This command helped me a lot to batch validate a lot of xml files:

xmllint --noout *.xml

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622995/check-xml-syntax-with-xmllint

Answer (score 0):

This error because of some xml files are not valid or somethings missing in xml files

What you need to do is disable module one by one and check error log and find out which module is caused for this problem and fix module's xml files

Or you can use xml validator tool to validate xml file